# Why defining a recursive-display procedure in Guile causes infinite loop?

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

The following procedure causes an infinite loop:

```
(define (recursive-display . args)
  (if (null? args)
      #t
      (begin
        (display (car args))
        (recursive-display (cdr args)))))
```

I'm still learning about Guile so I'm a bit confused why that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display` to print the value of `args` and look at the output:

```
(define (recursive-display . args)
  (if (null? args)
      #t
      (begin
        (display args)
        (recursive-display (cdr args)))))

> (recursive-display 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
((2 3))
(())
(())
(())
...
```

Your function `recursive-display` has a variable number of arguments. When you call something like `(recursive-display 1 2 3)`, all arguments passed to this function are wrapped in the list, so variable `args` has a value `'(1 2 3)`.

Next, you call `(recursive-display (cdr args))`. The same rule applies again- all arguments are wrapped in the list, so `args` has now value `'((2 3))`.

In all following iterations, `args` has a value `'(())`.

When you add [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29), it will work as expected:

```
(define (recursive-display . args)
  (if (null? args)
      #t
      (begin
        (display (car args))
        (apply recursive-display (cdr args)))))

> (recursive-display 1 2 3)
123#t
```